# ¿Cómo hacer hover correctamente en los elementos del menú dropdown?

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Estoy haciendo un menú de tipo dropdown para mi aplicación. El caso es que, al hacer el hover sobre el icono de dropdown, sólo puedo hacer hover a los dos primeros elementos. Después de eso, se cierra el menú de dropdown. ¿Cómo podría arreglarlo?

Código de la página de usuario:

```css
/* Vars file import */

 :root {
  --header-bg-color: #272d2d;
  --formBtn-bg-color: #4CAF50;
  --formRegister-bg-color: #4F7CAC;
  --navBar-links-color: #f2f2f2;
}


/***************************  GLOBAL STYLES ***************************/

body {
  height: 100%;
}


/***************************  GLOBAL STYLES ***************************/


/**************************  NAVIGATION BAR  **************************/


/* Navbar container */

.navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: fixed;
  /* Set the navbar to fixed position */
  top: 0;
  /* Position the navbar at the top of the page */
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  /* Full width */
  height: 80px;
  background-color: #272d2d;
}


/* Links inside the navbar */

.navbar a {
  float: right;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  height: auto;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}


/* The dropdown container */

.dropdown {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}


/* Dropdown button */

.dropdown .dropbtn {
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  background-color: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
  /* Important for vertical align on mobile phones */
  margin: 0;
  /* Important for vertical align on mobile phones */
}


/* Add an effect to navbar links on hover */

.navbar a:hover,
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  opacity: 0.5;
}


/* Dropdown content (hidden by default) */

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 200px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}


/* Links inside the dropdown */

.dropdown-content a {
  float: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}


/* Add a grey background color to dropdown links on hover */

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}


/* Show the dropdown menu on hover */

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

.dropdownMenuIcon,
.logoutMenuIcon,
.homeIcon {
  width: 45px;
  height: auto;
}

.dropdownMenuIcon:hover {
  background: url('../resources/icons/menu-black.png');
}

.logoutMenuIcon:hover {
  background: url('../resources/icons/logout-black.png');
}

.homeIcon:hover {
  background: url('../resources/icons/home-black.png');
}


/**************************  NAVIGATION BAR  **************************/


/************************** BODY CONTENT ***************************/

.bodyContainer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 60%;
  left: 0;
  margin-top: 8%;
  position: absolute;
}

.formTitle {
  text-align: center;
}

.formContainer {
  width: 25%;
  height: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}


/* Full-width inputs */

input[type=email],
input[type=password] {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


/* Set a style for all buttons */

button {
  background-color: var(--formBtn-bg-color);
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 20px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 50%;
}


/* Add a hover effect for buttons */

button:hover {
  opacity: 0.8;
}

.labelText {
  font-weight: bold;
}

#btnLogin {
  float: right;
  width: 50%;
}

#error {
  color: red;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  text-align: center;
}


/************************** BODY CONTENT ***************************/


/* TODO mover esto a otro archivo?? */

#userGreet {
  text-align: center;
}

.hiddenContent {
  display: inline-block;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <!-- CSS imports -->
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/main.css" />
  <!-- JQuery include -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
  <!-- <script type="text/javascript" src="js/loginForm.js"></script> -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>User panel</title>
</head>

<body>
  <!-- Navigation Bar content -->
  <div class="navbar">
    <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="dropbtn"><img src="https://placehold.it/45x45/" alt="Menu Icon" class="dropdownMenuIcon"></button>
      <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a href="#">Create a new user</a>
        <a href="#">Edit user</a>
        <a href="#">Link 3</a>
        <a href="#">Edit user</a>
        <a href="#">Link 3</a>
        <a href="#">Edit user</a>
        <a href="#">Link 3</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <a class="navBarElement" href="../index.php?logOut=true"><img class="logoutMenuIcon" src="../resources/icons/logout.png" alt=""></a>
  </div>
  <!-- Body content -->
  <div class="bodyContainer">
    <div id='userGreet'>
      <h3>Welcome, Nombre Apellido</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: A mí me funciona bien: https://jsfiddle.net/Kiko_L/84o1e46y/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La clase `bodyContainer` efectivamente tiene un absolute que no puedas acceder correctamente al menú, cambiándolo como tu mismo has  visto a `position: relative` soluciones este problema. Pero creo, si me permites el apunte, que además ya que tu menú es `fixed` puedes añadirle un `z-index` que lo posicione por delante del resto de elemento de la página, ya que supongo que la intención es que siempre quede accesible al usuario y por tanto debe mostrarse siempre en primer plano. Con esto en realidad no tendrías ni que cambiar el `position: absolute` del `bodyContainer`:

```
.navbar {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 80px;
    background-color: #272d2d;
    z-index: 99999; /*por ejemplo*/
}
```

Espero haberte podido ser de ayuda. 
Un saludo

Answer (score 3):

Acabo de encontrar la solución.

El contnedor del body tenía un position:absolute, lo que hacía que los elementos del menú de navegación no pudieran ser correctamente seleccionados.